# Calling multiple ansible playbooks in python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, ansible, ansible-2.x

How to trigger ansible playbooks from python.

Can i use ansible api or python subprocess which one most robust. In python script i want to execute multiple playbooks.

In ansible documentation they have mentioned python api only for Internal use.

Versions:
Ansible 2.7
Python 2.7

Comment: Maybe too much, but Ansible Tower or AWX, can build Playbook workflows that you can start from a REST API